# How do I copy a file to 'document root' of my Django web server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I really hit an impasse.

I wanted to download a file when I click a button.

The file is present in a network path and the Django server is also in the same network. I could open/reach the file using file explorer in windows.

However, when I try to download the file like this:

```
 success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            if(msg.zip == 'ok'){                    
                window.open('file:'+msg.te_logs);
            }              
        },
```

I get a console error:

```
**Not allowed to load local resource**:
file://PCName-labstore/Log_Database/Campaigns/log.zip
```

I am told Local file access is impossible (even though the server is in the network).

At this point, all I could think of is copying the .zip file somehow to document root, and then give that path to download and then delete the file from document root after download is complete.

I haven't done this before. Can you kindly advise me how?

Or if it is possible to open the network path using FileReader API, can you please point me to an example how? My Django server and all users who use my site/app have are on the same network as the network drive where the files are at.

Comment: Have you had a look at Django's [static files management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/)? Your web site could theoretically also display links to the network drive location directly using this syntax `file://server/share/folder/file`.

Comment: I am able to manually trigger a download on a browser if I copy the path to a browser like `file://server/share/folder/file` . But when I attempt to open using `window.open()` I get the error I shared. I am a little lost reading static file management.

Comment: Can you kindly expand a little more. I am still unable to download from document root